# How to disable auto-complete or auto-fill in react-select?

Tags: react-select, react-select-plus

How to disable auto-complete or auto-fill in react-select?
I need an answer without the involvement of the Input custom component.
Can you guys please help me to figure it out?

Comment: https://react-select.com/props

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom Input component and can use that component with react-select.
Something like this:-

```
import Select, { components } from 'react-select'

const Input = ({ ...rest }) =>
<components.Input {...rest} autoComplete={'nope'} />

<Select {...rest} components={{ Input }} />
```

Chrome now ignores `autoComplete="off"` unless it is on the `<form autocomplete="off">` tag.
So, that's why I'm using random string `autoComplete="off"`

Comment: This worked for me, although in Typescript I needed to adjust it slightly: `const Input = (inputProps: any) => <components.Input {...inputProps} autoComplete="nope" />`